# Gradle: jar task - override from

Tags: java, gradle

I need to customize my `jar` task so it would:

- process all classes as usual;
- include only particular resources and put them into custom folder inside the jar.

I've already made custom jar task, which does what I want:

```
task customJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn classes
    group = 'build'

    // everything except resources process as usual
    from sourceSets.main.output - sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir

    // and process resources to custom place
    from(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir) {
        include 'docs/**'
        include 'messages*.properties'
        into 'custom-folder'
    }
}
```

But I still need to replace built-in jar with a new one.

Replacing it with `create`

```
tasks.create(name: "jar", type: Jar, overwrite: true) {
    // ... custom jar spec
}
```

...yields

```
Replacing an existing task that may have already been used by other plugins is not supported
```

and simple configuration of the `jar` task doesn't work, because it is already configured in JavaPlugin:

```
jar {
    // jar is already configured
    // with `from sourceSets.main.output`
    // so it will include everything
    // AND create a custom folder

    // does nothing
    from sourceSets.main.output - sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir

    // adds processed resources into 'custom-folder'
    // in addition to all resources processed by default behaviour
    from(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir) {
        include 'docs/**'
        include 'messages*.properties'
        into 'custom-folder'
    }
}
```

So, what I need is to rewrite (override) default `from` configuration of `jar`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

you were there almost ..

```
tasks.create(name: "myJar", type: Jar) {
    // ... custom jar spec
}

jar.enabled = false //if you want to disable the default
build.dependsOn myJar //ensure this always runs
```

Comment: Yep, tried that. Turned out this approach is fine if I just want to create a custom jar, but it doesn't work if I then use a `project(':submodule')` dependency.

Comment: And I stated in the question, that I've already made working custom task. But what I want is to change behaviour of original built-in `jar` task.